# Delete partially similar rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to delete partially similar rows in a table, using MySQL. Ex:

From table1 (id,color1,color2,key) content:

```
id,color1,color2,key
-----------------------------
1,Blue,Green,AASDDD
2,Blue,Green,JJUUYYY
3,Blue,Red,HHYYY
4,Green,Red,KKIII
5,Blue,Red,KKIIUUUU
```

I'd like to delete the duplicate rows in color1,color2 and get:

```
id,color1,color2,key
-----------------------------
1,Blue,Green,AASDDD
3,Blue,Red,HHYYY
4,Green,Red,KKIII
```

Something like

```
delete FROM table1 WHERE Exists(SELECT color1,color2 FROM table1)
```

What's the best way to do this in MySQL without creating a temporary table?

(I know there are many posts about deleting duplicate rows in MySQL, but not for partially matching rows.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM table1 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT min(id) 
                 FROM table1 
                 GROUP BY color1, color2)
```

### edit

MySQL can't delete from a table with a subquery of the same table. To work around that limitation you can do this:

```
DELETE FROM table1 
WHERE id NOT IN (select * from (SELECT min(id) 
                               FROM table1 
                               GROUP BY color1, color2) t)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My question is specific for MySQL and with your query you get: [Err] 1093 - You can't specify target table 'verbal_sets' for update in FROM clause

Comment: You could use a temporary table to store the subquery and then delete all entries from table1 that are not in your temp table.

Comment: That's exactly what I would like to avoid. The table is huge and heavily indexed. There must be a way to do this in MySQL. I have it working perfectly under SQLite.

Comment: I believe this must not be the most efficient way to do it, but it certainly works. Thank you!

Comment: @MiguelE: I am sorry I can't come up with a better solution. You could use a temp table but this would be even slower.

Answer (score 3):

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT min(id) FROM table1 GROUP BY color1, color2)
```

Here you've manual for GROUP BY: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions-and-modifiers.html

Tutorials:

- http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlgroupby.php/
- http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

NOTE:

In MySQL:

> Currently, you cannot delete from a table and select from the same
>   table in a subquery.

At least for 5.0 version. ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html )

So in mysql you may use [TEMPORARY TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) in [transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html):

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE colors_temp SELECT min(id) as id FROM table1 GROUP BY color1, color2;
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM colors_temp);
DROP TABLE colors_temp;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Hi. In MySQL from this query you'll get: [Err] 1093 - You can't specify target table 'verbal_sets' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Your query works under SQLite or SQL Server, but under MySQL there is this restriction. You can find many posts about this, but I'm looking for a clean example to clean partial duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
   DELETE FROM table1 
   WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT MIN(id) FROM table1 GROUP BY colo1, color2)
```